# R convert list that has elements of varying size to a dataframe and count distinct/unique rows

Tags: r, list

How could i convert below list to a data.frame? I want to count unique elements in that list after sorting each element in ascending order. I am planning to convert the list into a data.frame, sort each row and then applying distinct().

In this case I want answer to be 3 as each element 3 and 4 are same when i sort them in ascending order

I would prefer functions from base R.

```
abcd=list()
abcd[[1]]=c(1,2)
abcd[[3]]=c(1,2,3)
abcd[[4]]=c(3,2,1)
> abcd

> as.data.frame(abcd)
Error in data.frame(c(1, 2), NULL, c(1, 2, 3), check.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 0, 3
> as.matrix(abcd)
     [,1]     
[1,] Numeric,2
[2,] NULL     
[3,] Numeric,3
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I want to count unique elements in that list.

Comment: I still don't quite get what you're after. Maybe just `length(unique(abcd))`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto sorry for confusion. I have clarified my question

Comment: @Jota, not a good idea to use `paste` with `collapse` here, since there might be edge cases you need to be careful of. Also, it's unnecessary to do all of that pasting and unlisting.

Comment: @AnandaMahto any better idea?

Comment: @user2543622, It's there [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32120931/1270695).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `length` + `unique` + `sort`, like this:

```
length(unique(lapply(abcd, sort)))
# [1] 3
# Warning message:
# In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

The `warning` is because of the `NULL` element. It can be suppressed with `suppressWarnings`:

```
suppressWarnings(length(unique(lapply(abcd, sort))))
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> abcd=list()
> abcd[[1]]=c(1,2)
> abcd[[3]]=c(1,2,3)
> unique(data.frame(unlist(abcd)))
  unlist.abcd.
1            1
2            2
5            3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table(unlist(abcd))

1 2 3 
2 2 1
```

Or if you want a data frame

```
data.frame(table(unlist(abcd)))

  Var1 Freq
1    1    2
2    2    2
3    3    1
```